# Proof that $x^4+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I've just started to work myself into the topic of irreducibility of polynomials and I would like to show the following:

> Prove that $x^4+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I've managed to come up with a proof that seems reasonable to me but I'm not sure if it is actually correct. Could someone tell me if I made any beginner's mistakes?

My proof: Clearly $x^4+1$ has no root in $\mathbb{Q}$, so it can only be decomposed into two polynomials of degree $2$. Therefore there must be $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $x^4+1=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1)$. If we multiply this out we get $x^4+(a+b)x^3+(ab+2)x^2+(a+b)x+1$. If we now equate the coefficients we get that $a+b = 0$ and therefore $a = -b$ and that $ab+2=0$ and therefore that $a^2=2$, which is not possible in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Why could it not be $(x^2+ax-1)(x^2+bx-1)$?

Comment: How do you know that the constant terms of the two quadratic factors have to be $1$? I think you need to invoke Gauß's lemma explicitly and work over $\mathbb Z$ to do that. (And even then, it would seem that @lulu's objection still applies).

Comment: For a different approach you can use a substitution $x\mapsto y+1$ to obtain a polynomial to which Eisenstein's criterion can be applied

Comment: @lulu Could we also use the quadratic formula to obtain $x^2= \pm i$? So, $x^4+1=(x^2-i)(x^2+i)$ which is not a factorization in $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Comment: @AlJebr  The fact that there are complex factorings does not immediately rule out the possibility of rational factorings.  For example, $x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ has complex roots (all the ninth roots of $1$ except for $1$ itself) but it also factors as $(x^2 + x + 1) (x^6 + x^3 + 1)$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach in principle works fine you just tried to take a short-cut that is not available, yet is not really needed. Instead:

$$(x^4+1) = (x^2+ax+c)(x^2+bx+d)$$

We get

$$x^4+(a+b)x^3+(ab+c+d)x^2+(ad+bc)x+cd.$$

You get $cd=1$ and thus $c=d^{-1}$. You still get $a=-b$ (from the third power), and then $ad +bc$ becomes $ad-ac$ and further $a(c^{-1}-c)$.

Thus, $a=0$ or $c= c^{-1}$ (that is, $c = \pm 1$).

In the former case, you get $c+ c^{-1}= c+d = 0$ which is impossible. In the latter case, you already dealt with $c=d=1$ and $c= d= -1$ is essentially the same,  it yields the impossible $a^2 = -2$.

That said, the Eisenstein approach mentioned in a comment is more elegant, if you have it available.

Answer (score 13):

For this polynomial, it can simplified, since we know its factorisation over $\mathbf R$:
$$x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2=(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2x+1),$$
and this factorisation does not have rational coefficients. So by the uniqueness of factorisation, it cannot have another factorisation over $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: Nice idea to show it like this. To avoid  potential over-generalization of this method by some reader, it might be worth stressing that this works because we know this factorization over the reals is the factorization into *irreducible* polynomials (over the reals). Just writing down some decomposition into two factors over the reals that is not one over the rationals does in general not suffice.

Comment: You're quite right. I just started from the initial observation of the O.P.

Comment: @Bernard, what if we notice that $f$ factorizes over $\mathbb{C}$ as $f = (X^2 - i)(X^2+i) = (X-\sqrt{i})(X+\sqrt{i})(X-i\sqrt{i})(X+i\sqrt{i})$, and then say that none of these factors is in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, and therefore $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Does this proof also work?

Comment: One point disturbs me:  $\sqrt i$ is not well-defined in $\mathbf C$. Other than that, it is correct, but a bit longer, as you would have to specify you would group factors by conjugate pairs.,.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I see, what is an alternative for writing $\sqrt{i}$? Or solving this in a similar way without using $\sqrt{i}$ explicitly? And could you explain the second point, about specifying to group factors by conjugate pairs?

Comment: You can give them explicitly: as $i=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2}$, its square roots are $\pm\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}4}=\pm\frac1{\sqrt 2}(1+i)$, and similarly for $-i=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}2}$, When you expand the product of conjugate factors, you  obtain each of the real quadratic factors. (beware the conjugate roots are not  opposite roots).

Answer (score 6):

Your proof is almost fine - you just have to write more generally
$$
x^4+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d),
$$
where we obtain of course $bd=1$, which over the integers only leaves the possibilities $b=d=1$, or $b=d=-1$. In both cases, the associated Diophantine equations have no solution, and this is easy to see (we obtain $c=−a$, and $a^2 =b+d=±2$, which is not possible).

Furthermore, the polynomial $x^4+1$ is the $8$-th cyclotomic polynomial, and hence irreducible by the theorem of your algebra lecture. Of course, there are several other methods to prove this directly, e.g., writing $f(x)=x^4+1$, and applying Eisenstein to
$$
f(x+1)=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+2.
$$

Comment: I can prove using Eisenstein that $f(x+1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, what does that say about $f(x)$?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat It says that $f$ is irreducible, see my answer.